# How to generate and count the 7x7 Latin squares

Tags: sudoku, latin-square

How many 7 by 7 Latin squares are there, and how can one generate examples of them? I am working on classes for a game, and typing in numbers manually from 1-7 in rows and columns from scratch is exceedingly difficult. From what I can tell there are no generators for this type of thing online.

Yes I can type in 1-2-3-4-5-6-7, then the next row 3-4-5-6-7-1-2, but that does not work so well with stats of classes in a game.

Diagonals do NOT have to be 1-7. Rows and columns must have a unique number per square.

Comment: Please clarify your conditions on the square. Does every row and column have to contain each number 1 through 7 exactly once? And the diagonals too?

Comment: Only rows and columns. Sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Pre-computed data for reduced Latin square is available at [Brendan McKay's website](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/latin.html).

Answer (score 8):

There are 61479419904000 seven by seven Latin squares. This is [from OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002860), and hard to calculate in general.

If you just want to generate Latin squares quickly, you have a few options. One is quick and lazy: take a few template squares, and then generate more by permuting the rows, columns, and/or numbers. If you're comfortable with programming, you can write a quick backtracking solver. Or you could use [this site](http://hamsterandwheel.com/grids/index2d.php). (Easy to Google once you know they're called, eh?)

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any nxn, with n being odd, there's a trivial solution where even the diagonals work:

1   6   4   2   7   5
2   7   5   3   1   6
3   1   6   4   2   7
4   2   7   5   3   1
5   3   1   6   4   2
6   4   2   7   5   3
7   5   3   1   6   4

Just start with 1-n in the first column, and in each next column shift down 2 positions ('as the knight jumps', if you will).

That's however only a partial answer, on how you can generate an example. Given your intended purpose I think you're more looking into a 'randomlooking' example?

EDIT:
Only after typing this up, I found it's covered in [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/the-quite-unusual-square/6384#6384) question aswell, but in more detail.