# The magic square with a hole

Tags: magic-square

Alice loves magic squares. She has a 4x4 square, where she can put a number in each cell. But alas! Some evil person has poked a hole in her square. Alice is really really sad because she can't make a magic square anymore. Won't you cheer poor Alice up?

> You are given a 4x4 square with 1 of its cells removed. Put the numbers 1 to 15 in it so that each row, column and diagonal sum to the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a few from [this site](http://www.cafe64.net/numbers/4x4/4x4_1.html). Any magic square with integers 0-15 will work, considering the 0 as a hole. I've chosen four with the 0 in the inner four cells just to be sure it meets your criteria. The rows, columns, and diagonals of each add up to 30.

[image]

Comment: The square can be constructed by [making a normal 4x4 1-16 square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#A_method_of_constructing_a_magic_square_of_doubly_even_order) and subtracting 1 from each cell.

Comment: Actually it can be done even if the hole (ie. 0) is in a corner or a side as well.

Comment: Building on @jingyu9575 his suggestion, you can extend the idea behind it up to (and maybe beyond) a 16x16 (http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/the-quite-unusual-square/6384#6384) , just reduce each of the numbers by one.